# using proxy from data in database, how to convert values to integer?

Tags: c#, proxy

I have a database with proxy information and want to test the proxies against google.com. The database has the following fields:

```
Proxy => ip
port => proxy port
authorization => is 1 if authorization is required
username => proxy username
password => proxy password
dead => 0 if proxy is working, 1 if not
```

Now i am trying to loop through my proxies and test them one by one. Everything seems to be OK, apart from the setting of the actual proxy port. My code expects an integer for port, the database field also is an integer, but when i try to set it to int, it doesnt work, gives "cannot convert object to int". When i try to use Convert.Toint32 it also errors, string not correctly formatted.

My code below:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //test proxies by connecting to them
            SQLiteDataReader reader = database.read_db("select * from proxies WHERE dead='0'");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string proxyadress = reader["proxy"].ToString();
                int proxyport = Convert.ToInt32(reader["port"].ToString());

                WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyadress,proxyport);
                if (reader["authorization"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(reader["username"].ToString(), reader["password"].ToString());  
                    proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;  //still use the proxy for local addresses
                }
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Proxy = proxy;

                try
                {
                    string doc = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/");
                    MessageBox.Show("proxy working");
                }
                catch
                {
                    //does not work
                    MessageBox.Show("proxy not working");
                }
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
```